# Next Palindrome generator

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the next Palindrome Number. I am trying to call a function called `fun()` to check the number is palindrome or not. My code did not work as expected... Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool fun(int n) {
    int m=n,r,re=0;
    while(n!=0) {
         r=n%10;
         re=re*10+r;
         n=n/10;
    }
    if(re==m) {
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
     int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--)//no of test cases
     {
         int n;
         cin>>n;
         n=n+1;
         if(fun(n)==true) {
             cout<<n<<"\n";// should print a number
             continue;
         }
         else {
             n=n+1;

             fun(n);// call for next number to be Palindrome
         }
     }
}
// if input : 808 output be 818 to be displayed on screen..
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but instead of writing `if(re==m) {
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        return false;
    }` you can simply write `return (re==m);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Palindrome number in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573385/palindrome-number-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your loop is all wrong. You need two loops, the outer loop is for test cases, the inner loop is to find the next palindrome. Something like this

```
int main()
{
    int test_cases;
    cin >> test_cases;
    for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; ++i)
    {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        num = num + 1;
        while (!is_palindrome(num))
        {
            num = num + 1;
        }
        cout << num << "\n";
    }
}
```

I've renamed some of your variables and functions. Names like `t`, `n` and `fun` are not adequate. Chosing good variable names helps *you* understand your own code, let alone anyone else.

Notice the inner loop, it loops *until* it finds a palindrome, that's why it uses not, `!is_palindrome(num)`. When a palindrome is found the inner loop is exitted, and only then does the number get printed. I think this logic was your main mistake, you used `if` where really you needed a `while` loop.

I haven't checked your palindrome testing function. There might be errors in there as well.